# Enabling the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options

Tags: c++, compilation

I try to compile a particular source code written in C++, and I do not get an executable file. Instead, I get the following message from the terminal:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/array:35,
                 from cpptesting.cpp:6:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

What does this message mean, and how can I fix the system? I have tried entering the directory 'include', but could find no 'c++' option. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you compile it? if you are using console command like `gcc .\cpptesting.cpp`, you should just add an option to it:
`gcc -std=gnu++0x .\cpptesting.cpp`

If you are compiling more complex program with `make`, check a makefile.
By the way, you are using pretty old gcc version, in the more recent versions this standard is enabled by default(IIRC).

Comment: OK;thank you. Add is there a difference between using g++ and gcc? I do not think I can do anything about the gcc version since I do not have admin privileges

Comment: gcc detects that file is c++ and then calls g++, so it doesn't matter, you can type `g++ -std=gnu++0x .\cpptesting.cpp`